# Transfer data from SQLite file to another

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data

How to transfer data from one SQLite file to another?

Any suggestions please , I want to transfer the data or read from one file to another.

Answer (score 1):

Read the data from the first file, write it to the second.

Comment: is there any simple example I am a newbie

Comment: First, download SQLite from the SQLite web site and play with the command line interpreter to become familiar with it.  Then find a good tutorial on iPhone such as Maher Ali's "iPhone SDK3 Programming" (there are likely others online) and read up on the SQLite interfaces.  There will be exercises in the tutorial that will take you through basic database operations.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a tutorial](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/) about using Cocoa-Touch and SQLite3.

Try and use it to create some code that tries to read and then write the database.

If this doesn't work - come back and ask a question with some specific code that we can fix.